Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted
const Settings = {
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  draggable: true,
  // swipe: false,
  currentSlide: activeLocation,
  afterChange: (newIndex: number) => {
    setActiveLocation(newIndex);
  },
};

const LocSettings = {
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1.5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  draggable: true,
  swipe:true
}; 

In NextJS, if I want to use swipe then I am commenting it but its giving this error:

Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

I want that swipe to be true. I can't make it false. What is the solution for this?
